# jQuery Mobile Refresh Element after AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'm using JQM 1.4.3. I have an AJAX that sets the value of a localStorage key and then changes the page:

**login.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'method=login&username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&token=' + encodeURIComponent(token),
    //async: false,
    //crossDomain: true,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    },
    success: function( user ){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        if(user) {
            $('#welcome').remove();
            storage.setItem("uid", user);
            storage.setItem("username", username);
            $('#welcome').trigger("create");
            $.mobile.changePage( "#page_dashboard", { transition: "slideup" });
            console.log(storage.username);
        }
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div data-role="content">
     <h2 align="center" id="welcome">Hello</h2>
</div>
```

**index.js (attached to index.html)**

```
$( document ).delegate("#page_dashboard", "pageinit", function() {
        $('#welcome').trigger("create");
        $('#welcome').text("Hello " + storage.username);
});
```

I'm attempting to refresh the value of text on #page_dashboard to reflect the new user. I'm using page_init and page_beforecreate and neither refresh the text. If I refresh the page manually the text changes. How do I refresh the element to reflect the new localStorage value?

Comment: If you're using JQM 1.3 or below, you need to `$.mobile.activePage.trigger("pagecreate")`.

Comment: Then `$("#headerID").toolbar()`.

Comment: It's not a jqm header...it's just text on the page wrapper in an html header tag.

Comment: Pls update your question with html markup and any relevant data.

Comment: if it's only a text, then `$("#welcome").text("new text")` not `.remove()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **"pageinit"** is triggered when the **DOM** is ready. If you want to do in
  only once then use **pageinit**.
- **"pagebeforeshow"** is triggered just before your page is showed. You
  can use this event when you need to do an action before displaying,
  like add div or HTML structure. ***If you need it each time page is
  visited then use pagebeforeshow***.

  ```
  $( document ).delegate("#page_dashboard", "pagebeforeshow", function() {
     $('#welcome').trigger("create");
     $('#welcome').text("Hello " + storage.username);
  });
  ```

Comment: I removed all references to #welcome in login.js and just set localStorage and then did the above in pagebeforeshow. Thanks!